# Array with nested Object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm curious as to how you would do this:

```
let x = [{}];
```

in TypepScript. I've looked around and can't find a clear answer to the question. My guess would be you do it using the Array object:

```
let x : Array<Object> = new Array<Object>;
```

or

```
let x : [{}] = [{}];
```

And using it in this context:

```
x.push({key: 'text', otherKey: 'text'});
```

Comment: Please be more specific. `let x = [{}];` is valid TypeScript and the type of `x` is correctly inferred.

Comment: What are you going to do with `x` after you assign it?  That will have some bearing on what, if any, type annotation you want to use.

Comment: @str I didn't know that was valid TypeScript.

Comment: @jcalz I will put in a better example

Comment: @PerryM JavaScript itself is valid TypeScript ;)

Comment: @str that is true...haha. I'm an AngularJS developer learning Angular 7 and this is reminding me so much of Java, I want to make sure I have the right context in regards to more complicated type specification

Comment: So, you want `x` to start out empty and then allow you to push *any* objects onto it?  Or just objects that look like `{key: string, otherKey: string}`?  If the former, then `let x: Array<object> = [];` will work.  If the latter, then `let x: Array<{key: string, otherKey: string}> = [];` will work.  If something else, then what?

Comment: @jcalz it was the former, but thank you for explaining both. Thank you so much for your help! If you put that as an answer I'll make sure to select it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this `let x : Object[] = [{}];`